# css compatibility issues with different browers

Tags: html, css, joomla, web, internet-explorer-9

I'm building a website in joomla 2.5 and making some good progress.  I'm not a great coder by an means but i know what to look for and where to insert most code.  I need some help though.  I've made a new module and things look great in Firefox and Chrome.  Looking at the page in IE9 though is not quite right.  Take a look at: http://southwestarkansasradio.com/joomla/.  The issue seems to be the "on air box" and then some spacing issue with the header.  Not sure how to fix these problems.  The on air box already has some compatibility code but i guess it's not exactly right.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The image "on air" has a style of "float:left" take that out and it fixes it

Comment: well partially fixed.  Still something funky.  Are you using IE9?

Comment: is the search box not wide enough?   It's not lined up right.  Also my on air box code has an issue somewhere inside, because the song info does not display in ie.  Thanks so much for your time and help.